# R dyplyr alternative for accross function

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a peice of code that I want to rewrite for an older version of dplyr, where there is no function `accross`.
Here is the code I have right now:

```
grouping_columns <- as_name(plot_columns[["xaxis"]])
grouping_columns <- append(grouping_columns, as_name(plot_columns[["color"]]))
data <- plot_data %>%
  group_by(across(all_of(grouping_columns))) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), offset = min(result_value),
            reorder_result_value = mean(result_value)) %>%
  as.data.frame
```

I am relatively new to R and days of google didnt help much...
I need the same result, but without `across`. The server I am deploying the shiny app has dplyr 0.8.5, and `across` came around 0.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group_by_at()` instead:

```r
  group_by_at(grouping_columns) %>%
```